# Split string into doublequoted and non doublequoted sections

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I'm currently working on a PHP project with a search engine which requires me to break down a search query to an array of substrings.
I want to support "doublequoting" so that the user is able to search for exact results e.g. "super secret stuff" only gets result with that exact string in their name while the same string without quotes returns results for "super" or "secret" or "stuff".
These quotes are supposed to be escapable.
Let me give you an example:

```
keyword Monday "Larrys \"House\"" epic
```

Should return an array of

```
[keyword, Monday, Larrys "House", epic]
```

I would like to support escaping of the backslashes too if this isn't too difficult to implement e.g. `\\"` still counts as a quote, while `\\\"` doesn't and so on.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use regex for this as php provides very good CSV parsing routines. Using [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$input = 'keyword Monday "Larrys \"House\"" epic';

$arr = str_getcsv($input, " ");

// remove \\ from array
$arr = array_map(function($elem) { return str_replace ( '\\\\', '\\', str_replace ( '\\"', '"', $elem ) );}, $arr);


// print resulting array
print_r($arr);
```

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/5UKm3A)

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => keyword
    [1] => Monday
    [2] => Larrys "House"
    [3] => epic
)
```

Comment: Could you provide a way to remove the escaping doublequotes like shown in the example?

Comment: Check my edited answer now.

Comment: Looks better, but I would replace `$arr[$i] = str_replace('\\', '', $arr[$i]);` with `$arr[$i] = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $arr[$i]);$arr[$i] = str_replace('\\"', '"', $arr[$i]);`not sure if this works as expected though

Comment: Anyways... This is (more or less) exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Nice use of `str_getcsv`! I'd add that a `foreach` instead of `for` makes more sense to me here.

Comment: Actually, we can avoid looping using `array_map` (edited).

Comment: @anubhava - even better!

Comment: Like I see this, this replaces every backslash with nothing... it works for most of the cases, but `\\ ` / escaped `\\\\ ` should be replaced with `\ ` /escaped `\\ `. And `\"` with `"`

Comment: @RoiEX: You can try: `$arr = array_map(function($elem) { return preg_replace('/\\\\(?=.)/', '', $elem); }, $arr);`

Comment: Almost... `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ ` is still being replaced with `\ ` but this doesn't matter. Feel free to edit your answer though. It's much better than the answer in the duplicated question